# What are the consequences of using an object as a key in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm a newbie to vue.js

For some reason, I had to use code like the following:

```
<view v-for="item in list" :key="item">
  <!-- do somethings -->
</view>
```

This seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if it's causing some problems, and I'm very, very sorry I didn't find a similar discussion elsewhere

Can I use it safely?

Thanks!

Comment: official doc if you want to take a look: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html. Short answer to you question: Vue needs to distinguish each item with a unique way that's why most of the times we put id as key.

Comment: Theoretically, it should work fine as long as Vue keeps using a `Map` to hold the keys: https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/3be4e3cbe34b394096210897c1be8deeb6d748d8/packages/runtime-core/src/renderer.ts#L1875.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) docs:

> Expects: number | string | boolean (since 2.4.2) | symbol (since 2.5.12)

If `item` is a JavaScript object, then you shouldn't use it as a key.  If you can't find any other key to use, then use the `v-for` index:

```html
<view v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">
  <!-- do some things -->
</view>
```

If the `item` object has a unique property like `id`, it would be best to use:

```html
:key="item.id"
```

As for the consequences, you get two warnings in the console, one which explains that duplicate keys were detected.  This is bad because it can cause a rendering update error.